# Virtualbox 5.0.2-102096 Unity Launcher not hidden in full screen

Tags: unity, virtualbox, launcher

I just updated to `VirtualBox 5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty` and now when putting the guest OS in fullscreen the Unity launcher stays over the top of the screen.

This is a returning issue, but in a new version of VirtualBox. The first release of Virtualbox 5 did not have this issue.

- Host: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Guest: Windows 8.1

Comment: given that you said that this originally worked in v5 but not v5.02 this is probably a virtualbox specific bug and as such should be reported to the virtualbox devs themselves to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed workaround is:

- Put the VB Guest in either windowed or full screen mode
- Lock the Ubuntu screen - VB Host - via the menu
- Unlock
- Put the VB Guest in full screen mode or go to windowed mode then back to full screen mode.

The launcher and top menu row then disappeared / behaved as wanted and expected.

Answer (score 0):

found same problem after update to virtualbox 5.0.2 in same situation above except for the guest os that is ubuntu 14.04 too. 
My temporary workaround is to work in gnome-flashback session with metacity , while using gnome-flashback with compiz gives the problem exactly like when i am in unity.